# Twitter REST API ruby gem rate limits for basic questions

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am working on creating a Business Intelligence warehouse for my employer and Twitter data is on the list. I am lost on the Twitter documentation. My goal is to create this list (dynamically)

- New Followers (past day,week,month)
- New Follows (past day,week,month)
- Messages received (past day,week,month)
- mentions (past day,week,month)
- messages sent, received (past day,week,month)
- retweets (past day,week,month)
- direct messages sent (past day,week,month)

Using the `ruby` `twitter` gem I called `client.followers` and explored the result to get a feel for it. However I got immediately rate limited and I also can't find anything in the documentation on Twitter on how to pass in date ranges for example.

Can anyone give me pointers on how to accomplish some of these requests? Do I need to keep bumping into the limit until I have for instance the date that each individual followed me and then roll it up myself?

Comment: as is stated below you will have to sign up for firehose but if you need to process multiple social media sources then I would suggest looking into [Gnip](http://gnip.com/sources) which twitter also owns. Gnip aggregates from sources like Twitter, Facebook, Instagram, Disqus, Tumblr and many many more...including Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explored this a while back & unfortunately, unless you sign up for Twitter's [firehose API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/firehose), you're going to have to deal with the limitations on their API.

It's their monetization scheme :-/ unfortunately everything isn't covered under the fremium business plan.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: thanks. It is fairly annoying that you can't even specify date ranges but instead I'll have to use the rate limited followers list method to just keep getting all the information about all the followers and work my way from there

Comment: hey Killerpixler, yea- except for Facebook and Reddit, these social network/media API's limitations can be really frustrating/can inhibit progress :/ Especially the Twitter and Instagram API's (they're the worst); hopefully with time and enough people filling customer support tickets, they may choose to provide more added functionality. Hope you have a great weekend ahead!! :0)